# Flutter: Syncfusion Chart Give Upper Limit to y-axis

Tags: flutter, linechart, syncfusion

I have a `SfCartesianChart` which displays a line chart of a list of values from 0 to 100, i.e. percentages. However, when there is a data point, for example, 99%, the upper limit of the y-axis seems like 120% which does not mean anything.

Here is my chart code

```
       SfCartesianChart(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          borderWidth: 0,
          plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
          title: ChartTitle(text: 'Mood Tracks', textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
          series: <ChartSeries>[
            LineSeries<MoodRecord, dynamic>(
                name: 'Moods',
                color: Colors.green[400],
                dataSource: records,
                xValueMapper: (MoodRecord record, _) => record.date,
                yValueMapper: (MoodRecord record, _) => record.mood.toInt(),
                dataLabelSettings: DataLabelSettings(isVisible: false),
                enableTooltip: true,
                animationDuration: 2000,
                markerSettings: MarkerSettings(
                    isVisible: true,
                    shape: DataMarkerType.circle,
                    color: kPrimaryColor
                )
              )
          ],
          primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
            labelPlacement: LabelPlacement.onTicks,
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          ),
          primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
            labelFormat: '{value}%',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)
          ),
        ),
```

Is there any way to define an upper limit on the y-axis? I do not want my chart to display something like 120% on the y-axis.

If there any better way to display percentages, it would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(maximum: 3.3)
```

Answer (score -1):

We have looked over the question and code and can inform you that the axis range is determined by the data source values. If you don't want values above 100 to be shown, use the [maximum](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/NumericAxis/maximum.html) property in the axis and manually customize the range. For more details, see the [help document](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/axis-types#customizing-range). You may also use the [numberFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/NumericAxis/numberFormat.html) property to reflect percentage values, as seen in the example below.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11519/how-to-apply-the-currency-format-to-the-axis-labels-sfcartesianchart

For 100 percent stacked charts, refer to the [support document](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/chart-types#100-stacked-column-chart), which converts the given data to 100 percent.

Answer (score -1):

```
SfCartesianChart(
    primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(labelStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 10,
    )),

    primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
        **minimum: 0, maximum: 100, interval: 25,**
        labelFormat: '{value}%',
        labelStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        fontSize: 10,
    )),
```

Comment: Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. Please take the [tour] and see [answer].